# AJAX: Passing multiple data

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hello I am having trouble passing multiple data through POST, also the hidden type can't get the ID at all.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 //##### Add record when Add Record Button is click #########
$("#FormSubmit").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
if($("#contentText").val()==='')
{
  alert("Please enter some text!");
  return false;
}

if($("#guestName").val()==='')
{
  alert("Please enter text!");
  return false;
}

var content = 'content_txt='+ $("#contentText").val(); //build a post data structure
var guest = 'guest_name='+ $("#guestName").val();
var article = 'article_id=' + $("#articleID").val();
jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST", // Post / Get method
url: "<?php echo site_url('article/create_comment/'); ?>", //Where form data is sent on submission
dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
data: "content_txt=" + content + "&guest_name=" + guest + "&article_id=" + article, //Form variables
success:function(response){
  $("#responds").append(response);
},
error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
  alert(thrownError);
}
});
});

});
```

when I run this I get as result:

guest_name=ttata-

content_txt=tatata

Instead of ttata and for content tatata

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered sending FormData instead of manually constructing the data format?  Sorry I can't comment yet so if you were asking a different question, I apologize.

e.g.

```
$("#FormSubmit").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData(document.forms.namedItem([form-name-here]);

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", ["your-action-here"], true);

    request.onload = function(e){
        if(request.status == 200){
            alert("Success!");
        } else {
            alert("Bummer!");
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
var content = 'content_txt='+ $("#contentText").val();
```

evaluates to "content_txt=ttata". Then

```
data: "content_txt=" + content + ...
```

evaluates to

```
"content_txt=content_txt=ttata"
```

So use either

```
var content = $("#contentText").val();
```

or

```
data: content + ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you've defined your variables:

```
var content = 'content_txt='+ $("#contentText").val(); 
......
```

Then in your Ajax call here is how you're putting your data together:

```
data: "content_txt=" + content  + '&.....'
```

Anything wrong with that picture?

Answer (score 0):

You can try sending the data as JSON. Just add a parameter of dataType: "JSON" then pass your data as a JSON object like so....

{content_text: content, guest_name: guest, article_id: article}